# AFNetworking JSON Issue

Tags: objective-c, json, ios6, afnetworking

I keep receiving the following error message: `2013-01-22 01:44:43.091 Section3App2[16625:6703] -[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x23a48780` after submitting my AFNetworking Request. The idea behind the request is that we are sending a post request to a REST API with a JSON Request Body via POST.  I have been fiddling with this all day and can't seem to figure out whats causing the problem.

**CODE**

```
NSString *string = @"[{\"code\": \"105N14560\"}]";
    NSString * jsonString = string;
    NSData * data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError * error = nil;
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
        [request setHTTPBody:json];
       // [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", string.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        NSLog(@"request body:%@", request.HTTPBody);
       // NSLog(@"json: %@",json);
//    if (!json) {
//        // handle error
//        NSLog(@"fail");
//    }
        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation2 = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", JSON);
        } failure:nil];
        [operation2 start];
```

That code successfully creates the request body but when it tries to run the block it throws the error and I'm completely stumped. All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Notice that you are passing `json` as the argument to `setHTTPBody:`. This should be an `NSData` object per the docs, but you've passed it an `NSArray` by deserializing te JSON string you constructed. Just pass `data` as your argument, you don't need to deserialize the JSON prior to posting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never try to build the JSON string yourself like you're doing in the first line. Use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert from a JSON-compatible Obj-C data structure (like `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`) directly to an `NSData` object to use as the body of the request. For example:

```
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"105N14560" forKey:@"code"];
id JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSON options:0 error:error];
```

You should use the resulting `JSONData` object for both the `HTTPBody` of the request as well as the `content-length` of the request. Here is a complete example:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL]; // URL = wherever the request should be sent to 

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

id JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSON options:0 error:error];
if (JSONData) {
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[(NSData *)JSONData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:JSONData];
}
```

This just creates the request. The rest of it is straightforward using `AFNetworking`, where using `AFJSONRequestOperation` you just pass in the request as you've already done.

Comment: Thanks Matt! The request is now sending properly and I believe the error now lies within the API